# Cookie detection inbetween Express and Passport

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, passport-facebook

Users visiting `http://localhost/login` are instantly redirected to Facebook for confirmation of application usage. Once authorized, Facebook contacts `http://localhost/login?code=` with a special code that allows the server to obtain the user's information such as their name and gender.

```
Express().get('/login', Passport().authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost/',
}), function(req, res) {
    database.saveData(req.user, **randomlyGeneratedHash**);
    res.cookie('session', **randomlyGeneratedHash**);
    res.end();
});
```

This works as expected, but when authenticated users visit the `/login` in succession, the whole process is repeated and they get a new cookie.

Is there a way that I can run some code inbetween Express and Passport, to stop Passport from redirecting to Facebook if the user has a valid cookie already?

Comment: 1. express.session already handle cookie 2. you can tell passport how to serialize/deserialize. Example: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/tree/master/examples/login

Comment: @damphat In the example provided, visiting the website at `/auth/facebook` or `/auth/facebook/callback` will not check for a cookie. It will simply `The request will be redirected to Facebook for authentication` -- as quoted from the comments in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to [`ensureAuthenticated`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/examples/login/app.js#L119) on your `/login` route:

```
var CheckIfAlreadyLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/'); // or where you want them to go
  }
  next();
};

Express().get('/login', CheckIfAlreadyLoggedIn, Passport().authenticate('facebook', ...));
```

This would redirect users that are already logged in back to `/` when they try to access `/login`.

Comment: Thank you! I had originally messed up thinking that `.get` was documented [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.get), but now I can clearly see that it is `app.VERB(path, [callback...], callback)` stated [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB).